# Bokeh change source data in CallbackJS

Tags: javascript, python, django, bokeh

I am trying to create a bokeh plot in a Django app to graph swimming events for an athlete. I am plotting duration (time swam) vs date (date of swim meet). The idea is to have one plot and be able to use a SelectBox widget to choose which event is shown on the graph. The problem is that when I change the source of the data in a CallbackJS function, the graph does not update and instead goes blank.

The data comes from Event objects of the form

```
class Event(models.Model):
    swimmer = models.ForeignKey(Swimmer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICE, null=True, blank=True)
    event = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=EVENT_CHOICE)
    time = models.DurationField()
    place = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    date = models.DateField(null=True)
```

First, I iterate through each of the events (17 currently) and makes a list of the date (datetime.date) and time (datetime.timedelta) fields. The unmodified fields are used for x and y respectively, and the values are edited slightly (mostly type cast to string) to be used for the hover tool. If there is no data for the particular event, the `data_source{}` entry is set to `None`.

Example data:

```
data_source = {
    'x_50_free': [date(2017,9,7), date(2017,9,8)]
    'y_50_free': [timedelta(seconds=22.96), timedelta(seconds=22.32)]
    'date_50_free': ['9/7/2017', '9/8/2017']
    'time_50_free': ['00:22.96', '00:22.32']
    'x_100_free': [date(2017,9,7)]
    'y_100_free': [timedelta(seconds=49.86)]
    'date_100_free': ['9/7/2017']
    'time_100_free': ['00:49.86']
}
```

Then, I plot an initial line so that a line is displayed when the page loads.

```
source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(
    x=data_source['x_'+first_event],
    y=data_source['y_'+first_event],
    date=data_source['date_'+first_event],
    time=data_source['time_'+first_event]
))
plot.line('x', 'y', source=source)
```

I update the source data in my callback function

```
callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source=source), code="""
    data = %s;
    f = cb_obj.value;

    if (f == "50 Freestyle") {
        source.data['x'] = data.x_50_free;
        source.data['y'] = data.y_50_free;
        source.data['date'] = data.date_50_free;
        source.data['time'] = data.time_50_free;
    } else if (f == "100 Freestyle") {
        source.data['x'] = data.x_100_free;
        source.data['y'] = data.y_100_free;
        source.data['date'] = data.date_100_free;
        source.data['time'] = data.time_100_free;
    }

    ...

    } else if (f == "400 IM") {
        source.data['x'] = data.x_400_im;
        source.data['y'] = data.y_400_im;
        source.data['date'] = data.date_400_im;
        source.data['time'] = data.time_400_im;
    }

    source.change.emit();
""" % json.dumps(data_source, cls=DatetimeEncoder)) # encoder to handle datetimes for x-axis
```

From what I understand, `source.change.emit()` is used to update the ColumnDataSource. This seems to work as I am able to log `source.data[]` to the console and see it update depending on the `Select` widget option, but the plot itself does not update it simply goes blank. How do I also update the plot to reflect the change in source data?

Comment: Could you please post a complete (but minimal) example of what you are doing? Especially including some mock data and your definition of the callback.

Comment: @mc51 yes just did it! Let me know if you need anymore information. I feel like I'm so close, it's just a matter of the plot itself not updating.

Answer (score 1):

Your example is neither minimal nor complete. A complete example can be run right away. A minimal one leaves out aspects not related to your issue. Hence, I am not really sure that I've understood everything but I tried to adapt it. Here is some code to get you started:

```
from bokeh.io import show, output_file, output_notebook
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.layouts import column, widgetbox
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, Select

output_file("swim_plot.html")

first_event = "_50_free"
second_event = "_100_free"

data_source = {
    'x': [date(2017,9,3), date(2017,9,4)],
    'y': [0, 0],
    'x_50_free': [date(2017,9,7), date(2017,9,8)],
    'y_50_free': [22.23, 24.34],
    'x_100_free': [date(2017,9,12), date(2017,9,14)],
    'y_100_free': [23.22, 25,12]
}    
source = ColumnDataSource(data=data_source)

callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source=source), code="""
    data = source.data;
    f = cb_obj.value;
    if (f == "_50_free") {
        data['x'] = data.x_50_free;
        data['y'] = data.y_50_free;
    } else if (f == "_100_free") {
        data['x'] = data.x_100_free;
        data['y'] = data.y_100_free;
    }
    source.change.emit();
""")

select = Select(title="Option:", value="default", options=["default",
                first_event, second_event])
select.js_on_change('value', callback)   

plot = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400, x_axis_type='datetime')
plot.line('x', 'y', source=source)    
show(column(widgetbox(select),plot))
```

The main issue I see with your code is the definition of ColumnDataSource. While you add all data to your data_dict you add only part of that to your source. Consequently, trying to access the missing data in your JS callback will fail.

Comment: So sorry about the poor example, the whole thing is a little long and I wasn't sure what might be relevant but it seemed unnecessary to include everything I'll work on that in the future. Is there anything I can provide right now that might help?

Comment: As for your answer, why do you define an 'x' and 'y' separate from 'x_50_free', 'y_50_free', etc.? The reason I defined my source the way I did was to establish the keys 'x', 'y', 'date', and 'time' in the ColumnDataSource, and then could change the values later. Do I have to add all data to ColumnDataSource in order to access it later? Because like I said before I could log source.data to the console when the Select was changed and the data changed, but the plot wasn't updating, so I originally thought it was an issue with triggering a plot update and not getting the data to change properly.

Comment: yes, you have to add your data to ColumnDataSource. that's what i meant in the last sentences.